# Using separate directory for each version of the API

Tags: php, laravel, api, api-versioning

I'm planning to create an API with Laravel framework. And there may be multiple versions of the API if I continue developing it, like: `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, and so on.

And instead of having only one copy of Laravel framework and versioning the API inside it by creating different directories for each version, I'm thinking of creating a completely separate copy of Laravel framework for each version of the API.

For example, suppose this is the URL of the API: `website.com/api`, I'm thinking of creating a directory called `v1` inside that `api` directory, and put a complete copy of Laravel in it. And later when I need to create a new version of the API, I will create another new directory called `v2` beside `v1` and put a new complete and separate copy of Laravel in it, and so on.

This way, when I want to access version 1 of the API, I will access this URL: `website.com/api/v1` and when I want to access version 2, I will access `website.com/api/v2`.

My question: Is this a bad idea? And what are the disadvantage of this approach?

---

**Edit:**

Why did I think of this approach?

Because I thought of the following points:

- What if I wanted, someday, to create a new version of the API with a PHP framework other than Laravel.
- What if I wanted, someday, to create a new version of the API with a programming language other than PHP.
- What if I wanted, someday, to upgrade to a newer version of Laravel and that version has significant changes to the version that the API was originally created with.

Comment: I can't find a single advantage as opposed to a disadvantage, why would you want this?

Comment: **You aren't gonna need it** (acronym: YAGNI) is a principle of extreme programming (XP) that states a programmer should not add functionality until deemed necessary.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it

Answer (score 9):

I believe it's a bad idea - heaps of duplicate code, duplicate maintenance and absolutely no advantages.

**Build for the Current Use Case**

First of all:

> You need to build technology to meet the current use case (and very
>   near future)

So many CTOs / technology architects get it wrong by sometimes thinking too much into the future. What if my volume increases 1000x? Should I use a big data stack? No, certainly not unless you anticipate it happening in the next 3 months!

**Disadvantages of your approach**

1. **Code duplicity:** You would end up duplicating so much code - your Eloquent models, business logic, authentication, middleware, etc.
2. **Maintenance & Other Overheads:** Depending on your tech stack, maintenance would also be duplicated. For e.g. imagine running Artisan commands on multiple apps for a simple config cache refresh. Not to mention separate upgrades on dependencies, hardware resources, etc.

**Advantages**

There are no apparent advantages of your approach. Let's look at the specific questions that drove you towards this architecture:

1. What if I wanted, someday, to create a new version of the API with a PHP framework other than Laravel?

Let's say you currently have 3 versions and you want to create version #4 on a different framework. Well, you can still have the first 3 versions on a single Laravel app and the 4th version on a different app / codebase. If you already have 3 existing versions, there's no reason to have them as separate Laravel apps

2. What if I wanted, someday, to create a new version of the API with a programming language other than PHP.

Well, the same applies here as well. You can always have different apps for future versions in different languages if such situations arise

3. What if I wanted, someday, to upgrade to a newer version of Laravel and that version has significant changes to the version that the API was originally created with.

Minor versions are backward compatible in Laravel. So, if you upgrade from say Laravel 5.1 to 5.5, there should be no breaking changes. For major ones, you can choose different apps (if required) but really, even major version upgrades may not be a challenge. Of course, you can use tools such as [Laravel Shift](https://laravelshift.com) to make upgrading easy for you

Answer (score 6):

My recommendations:

### Use Subdomains

Let your api be available at urls like: `mobile.laravel.app` or `api.laravel.app`.

This gives you the flexibility to use a different server (and hence a different framework) for your api, or continue using the same laravel app for your application. You can use [sub-domain routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing) in laravel to handle multiple domains using the same app.

### Your Versioning strategy

One typically keeps version no.s of api as {major}.{minor} (inline with semantic versioning). Minors being backward compatible.

e.g.

```
api.laravel.com/v1.2/...
```

or

```
v1.api.laravel.com/...
```

(esp. if it points to different ip Address).

Again you can choose to point to a different sever or folder, or different controller, based on what changes you are doing.

#### Using Laravel for versioned API

Most of the projects that I work on are on Laravel, and this is how we handle versioning in Laravel.

Apis are received at a subdomain like: `api.laravel.app`

APIs are versioned, and available at `api.laravel.app/v1/...` or `api.laravel.app/v2/...`

The controllers handling these APIs are grouped in folders

```
App
|-Http
  |-Controllers
     |-API
        |-v1
           - controllers for v1
        |-v2
           - controllers for v2
```

If at a future date, you'd like to change the servers, platform or use a different version of laravel etc - you can handle via a different subdomain.

I would still recommend working on a "roadmap" and com-template features and version no.s for next 3-6 months at a time.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm thinking of creating a completely separate copy of Laravel
>   framework for each version of the API.

Why you want to duplicate whole framework, there's no point doing so. As doing so you will have many versions of same file, and this will end up with duplicate code. What if you find a bug in common method among all 
versions, you have to change it in all versions.

> - What if I wanted, someday, to create a new version of the API with a PHP framework other than Laravel.
> - What if I wanted, someday, to create a new version of the API with a programming language other than PHP.
> - What if I wanted, someday, to upgrade to a newer version of Laravel and that version has significant changes to the version that the API
>     was originally created with.

Your all 3 points doesn't relate to how you are organising your API, as soon as you change language or framework, you will have to rewrite it, except it's only a version change.

And making API structure based on foreseeing a Language change or framework, does not make sense. **Ebay, Paypal, Facebook, Google etc, all have changed their language of choice and rewritten their code base at certain point of time. They hadn't foreseen this change and made their system according to that.**

So there are lots of disadvantages I can see.

### Approach 1:

Rather I prefer as best practice is **version control your API's in different branches or tag them** like laravel itself is doing. *(see image below)*

[image]

#### Advantages :

- Easily switch between API's
- Comfortable with IDE, as there won't be same name files to search and edit, so you won't edit different version by mistake.
- Any time you can update any version.
- See change history
- many more you will experience while developing with this approach over different folder copies.

### Approach 2:

Another option I can see and I've done is that grouping your API's with version specific prefix. If you want all versions to be running at a time with single copy. But this is less recommended.

**Change method name or controller name as per version, or put them in version specific name space**

See snippet below:

```
/* Version v1  */
Route::prefix('v1')->group(function () {
    Route::get('users','UsersController@index');
    Route::get('foobars','FooController@bar');
});

/* Version v2  */
Route::prefix('v2')->group(function () {
    Route::get('users','UsersController@index'); 
    Route::get('foobars','FooController@bar');
});
```

#### Advantages :

- Run all versions at a time in a single project,
- Well organised, routing,
- Namespace wise versions of Controllers, models. (You may leave common controllers, and prefix method names with version number instead, to reduce copy paste work).
- No branch switching

*Note: Both are situation specific approaches, if there are less than 5 or 10 changes in new version, I would go for approach 2. However this is individual specific choice.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct. This is a very bad idea. And the challenge is to even think of a single advantage but there is none.

I'll recommend you stick with one installation, and you can use [Dingo API](https://github.com/dingo/api/) . A package that would provide you with a set of tools and standard API practices right out of the box. Including versioning like `v1`, `v2` as you want.

This will improve your code reusability alongside many other things that would help you build a standard API.

Good luck.

Comment: One benefit is could engineer the system to fall back this class/method is not in V2 so load the V1 version this way you don't have duplicate code across the versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer to this question, and since you said you "plan" to use laravel, I want to recommend another platform that supports REST API versions.

https://apigility.org/

Apigility, use zendframework as a base, if you are interested in using another framework, I recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correct, you are "mixing" your development and deployment architecture.

I don't see any problem in you production environment having multiples versions of your API based on the url path (as you suggested), or even sub-domains.

Your control version (git, svn, etc.) should take care of each API version you may have. If you want to develop a new version: create a new branch, develop and test it, then create a tag.

Then, when you deploy the application itself, you'd care about how to make it accessible through an specific path or domain.